# PouchDB: Como excluir todas as bases de dados?

Tags: pouchdb

Pela que vi na documentação do PouchDB é possível aplicar `db.destroy()`, porém, só na base de dados criada/escolhida.

É possível excluir todas as bases de dados (diretamente pelo PouchDB)?

Answer (score 1):

PouchDB fornece um plugin para isso:

https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-all-dbs

```
PouchDB.resetAllDbs();
```

Comment: Ou mesmo sem o plug-in é possível fazer uma chamada rest para [`/_all_dbs`](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API#List_Databases), iterar sobre  resultado e chamar `db.destroy()` em cada um deles (provavelmente é isso que esse plug-in está fazendo).

Comment: Interessante, Anthony. Vou testar sua sugestão. Obrigado.

Comment: Me parece que essa funçao _all_dbs foi depreciada no PouchDB 2.0. Ou estou enganado?

Comment: O  [recurso rest](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/server/common.html#get--_all_dbs) continua lá. O que foi removido é a função da API, eis o motivo de existência desse plugin. Veja a nota [no manual](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-all-dbs/blob/master/README.md) do plug-in.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado!